# Want to fire IBAction on Touch up Inside of Static TableViewCells

Tags: ios, xcode, static, uitableview

I have a Static TableViewCells on a storyboard. There are just labels in those cells. I would like to fire IBAction event upon touch. What I am doing right now is create a full-size white button and linked to IBAction. But it doesn't show highlighted color when the cell is selected because cell is behind the button.

Comment: To clarify my question, I want to fire IBAction when the cell is touch. I don't know how to do without placing white button on the cell.

Answer (score 3):

UITableViewCells have a delegate method specifically for handling row touches [-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a)

If you need a custom button over each cell, subclass UITableViewCell instead of going through a storyboard.  As much as they may be a timesaver, storyboards are really a limiting factor when it comes to nitty gritty iOS programming.

Comment: I used static cells and there are four groups. I learnt that if I am using static cells, those delegates should be disable. Is that true?

Comment: @CodaFi - static content table views in storyboards dont recycle cells, nor do you implement the datasource methods. The delegate is fine to connect though, and didSelectRow souds like a good place to implement this.

Comment: @zhtway - delegate methods are fine. It's the datasource methods you shouldn't implement.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath (when you initialize each cell):

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

Does this fix it?